# change embedded resource file during runtime

Tags: c#, resources, embedded-resource

I have a written a program that uses a resource (embedded TEXT file) for the programs default configuration. i want to be able to allow users to change this default behavior. i would like to know how to modify the embedded resource file so that following times program is used it would use the modified version.

appreciate the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [`settings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) file. 
The embedded resources are compiled into your exe/dll and are not meant to be modified.

Comment: thanks, i wish i would of used settings at the start of this project currently it would be to risky to convert all links used to settings.

Answer (score 3):

here is one way to update file which is embedded in the project , here is an example of xml file. You can change it to txt file as per your need

```
string path = Path.Combine(
Environment.GetFolderPath(
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), 
Application.CompanyName);

path = Path.Combine(path, Application.ProductName);
path = Path.Combine(path, subFolder);
path = Path.Combine(path, "fileName.xml");

if(!File.Exists(path)){
    Assembly thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Stream rgbxml = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
"YourNamespace.fileName.xml");          
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(rgbxml);

    doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    doc.Save(path);
```

check full article : [**SAVING AN EMBEDDED RESOURCE XML FILE AT RUNTIME IN C#**](http://weblogs.asp.net/cfrazier/archive/2005/07/18/419812.aspx)

Comment: i tried the code above, but i keep getting null from the line: **Stream rgbxml = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(
"YourNamespace.fileName.xml");** i might be placing a bad namespace but i cant seem to figure out why

Comment: @james - i shared link of full article if possible have look to it ...it explain all things

Comment: reading the information in the link, i am not sure this does what i want. i am not sure this modifies the file only saves it.

Answer (score 0):

you better try using Properties to save settings , Example:
Properties.Settings.Default

To add properties , in solution explorer right click ->Properties->Settings(Tab)

Then Add whatever you need , then in code access from .Default

To save your updates settings in runtime use the following:
Properties.Settings.Default.Save()

Hope this helps