# Change color path inside svg in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, svg, xamarin.forms

i have this simplified svg file, the mean idea is i want to change the color of some path in svg file.

```
<?xml..>
<svg..>
<g >
    <path id="cp1589"style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;" d="m 547.96,1140.. z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

and this is the simplified plan.xaml

```
<?xml ..>
<ContentPage ..>
    <abstractions:SvgImage Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}"
                           SvgPath="{Binding SvgPath}"/>
</ContentPage>
```

the simplified Plan.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class Plan : ContentPage
    {
        public string SvgPath { get; set; }
        public Assembly SvgAssembly { get; set; }
        public Plan()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SvgPath = "Test.Images.Plan.svg";
            SvgAssembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

            BindingContext = this;
            Stream stream = SvgAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(SvgPath);
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(stream);
            var circle = xml.GetElementsByTagName("path");
            for (int i = 0; i < circle.Count; i++)
            {
                var path = circle[i].Attributes;
                for (int j = 0; j < path.Count; j++)
                {
                    XmlNode node = path[j].SelectSingleNode(".");
                    if (path[j].Name.Equals("style"))
                     node.Value = "fill: rgb(0, 128, 0);";                                  
                }
            }
            //xml.Save(stream);
        }
    }
```

the problem is , the color dosent change..

Comment: you are not saving the file after you change it

Comment: thanks for ur answer,             //xml.Save(stream);
cuz this line generate an error , and i think i can't save ? (            SvgPath = "Test.Images.Plan.svg";
) plan.svg is an  embedded resource.

Comment: You can't write to an embedded resource at runtime.  Everything in the app bundle is read-only.  You can write a copy to writable path in the file system.

Comment: how write a copy to writable path? i tried to convert the xml to bytes and using MemoryStream , but dosent work ..

Comment: `xml.Save(filepath);`

Comment: i cant write to an embedded ressource ! xml.Save("Test.Images.Plan.svg") generate an error !

Comment: I know you can't write to a resource, that's why I suggested writing a copy to a writable path.  There are extensive docs on files in XF, please read them.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows

Comment: after saving in /filepath , how can i binding this new filepath to show the modification in the xaml.

Comment: just set the SvgPath to the new filepath

Answer (score 1):

We could not do that with `SvgImage`.

When we use the `SvgImage`, we must set Build Action to `Embedded Resource` for our svg files. https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/SVG

But the embedded resources are compiled into our exe/dll and are not meant to be modified. [change embedded resource file during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174425/change-embedded-resource-file-during-runtime)

I have tried to save the stream into internal storage and update the SvgPath with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. But like what i said at first time, the svg we saved must be `Embedded Resource`. We could not do that. Below is the error when i try to load from storage.

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Error retrieving /data/user/0/com.companyname.app4/files/file1.svg make sure Build Action is Embedded Resource)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading).

(Nuget packages: Xamarin.FFImageLoading, Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms, Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg and Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms)

First you have to make the changes to the svg and get the resulting svg content:

```
Stream stream = SvgAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(SvgPath);
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(stream);
...
using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings{
    Indent = true,
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
};
using XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, settings);
xml.WriteContentTo(writer);
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
string modifiedSvg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

Then you can use [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/SVG-support) to create a new SVG.

```
SvgImageSource.FromSvgString(modifiedSvg)
```

This ImageSource you can display for example with [SvgCachedImage](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/SVG-support#xamarinforms).

Comment: thanks for u effort , nothing happend ..!

Comment: @DevQc of you provide further information on what you tried, I can provide further assistance. I am sure it is possible, since I successfully implemented this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FFImageLoading to Tint your svg images as per your program conditions(true/false) you can change the tint.

Comment: i tried with FFImage , nothing happend when i call (            SVGFile.Source = SvgImageSource.FromSvgString(modifiedSvg);)